# Iterar sobre una lista de elementos web con selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo inconvenientes para poder acceder a cada uno de los elementos de un listado web con selenium (https://www.cineplanet.cl/peliculas), el código que tengo permite realizar la navegación por la web pero lamentablemente no sale del primer elemento, repite el proceso una y otra vez sobre el primero. Me gustaría acceder a cada una de las películas de la cartelera y realizar los pasos que ya tengo logrados. Adjunto el código agradeciendo la ayuda.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

URL = 'https://www.cineplanet.cl/peliculas'
PATH = 'C:\\Program Files\\chrome-driver\\chromedriver.exe'
XPATH_COMPRAR = '//div[@class="movie-info-details"]/div[@class="movie-info-details--wrapper"]/div[@class="movie-info-details--first-button-wrapper"]/button'
XPATH_FUNCIONES = '//h3[@class="cinema-showcases--summary-name"]'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5)

listado_peliculas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('movies-list--large-item')

while len(listado_peliculas):
    for movie in listado_peliculas:
        item = driver.find_element_by_class_name('movies-list--large-movie-description-title').text
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH_COMPRAR).click()
        funciones = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH_FUNCIONES)
        for x in range(0,len(funciones)):
            time.sleep(3)
            ActionChains(driver).click(funciones[x]).perform()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.back()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.movies-list--view-more-button-wrapper .call-to-action--text')
```

Estoy usando un entorno virtual con Python 3 y las librerías correspondientes para usar selenium.

Cabe destacar que se me ha complicado ya que la pagina en cuestión carece de links, ID, value, etc., en sus etiquetas adicional tampoco cambia sus direcciones en el dominio.

Comment: Estoy intentando seguir los pasos que indicas en tu código, y para hacer click sobre el boton comprar, ¿No deberias antes hacer un mouse over sobre el elemento? Sin eso dudo que puedas interaccionar con el boton comprar. Ademas ese path de comprar te devuelve 6 elementos uno por cada boton comprar y por tanto siempre dará al primero. Tal vez sea ese el problema. Debes tratar los botones de comprar como otra lista.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Lamentablemente no pude resolver de esa manera, el problema está en el DOM (Documente Object Model) que cambia al refrescar o regresar a la pagina del listado por lo que cuando intenta iterar sobre los elementos se genera la excepción ya que se pierde en los elementos. Actualmente pude resolver el acceso a cada peliclua de la cartelera pero usando otros medios. Saludos

Comment: Claro cuando vuelvas a la pagina con el listado de peliculas debes obtener de nuevo los elementos de la lista, porque su referencia ya habrá cambiado al abandonar la pagina y volver

Comment: Pero el problema es que como se lograría ubicar la ejecución en el siguiente elemento, fíjate que estoy en otra parte de la página y me encontré con el mismo problema, estoy tratando de resolver por otras vías pero es que la pagina no tiene nada en sus etiquetas (id, value, href, etc)

Comment: Necesitarias un contador para saber por que elemento vas, o obtener el titulo de la pelicula, guardarlo en una lista y antes de interaccionar con el elemento de la lista de peliculas, comprobar si su nombre esta en la lista de tratadas ya. Para el problema de los identificadores XPath es muy potente. Si editas tu pregunta y expones un poco mejor el resultado final que esperas obtener, tal vez pueda ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ya he intentado de esa forma, pero las etiquetas no guardan relación. Acerca de los xptah los he usado, pero los cambié todos a css ya que lo que indican en los comentarios de foros y otras respuestas en stackoverflow no favorecen mucho el uso de los mismos.